# rqt_console doesn't display all messages

Tags: ros, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My post is a duplicate of [this post](https://answers.ros.org/question/300367/rqt_console-tool-doesnt-display-message/) which was closed for unknown reasons. ROS users keep commenting under that post which means that the problem still exists!

Basically, `rqt_console` does not display all the messages from all nodes even though `rqt_logger_level` "sees" the nodes and the proper logging levels are set up.

Any solution to this problem?
Is there any workaround?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371523/rqt_console-doesn%27t-display-all-messages/) by [mac137](https://answers.ros.org/users/69218/mac137/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2021-02-10

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I was having a similar issue today. I was able to fix it by going to the rqt_console settings in the GUI, and then switching the Rosout Topic in the drop down menu from /rosout_agg to /rosout.

---

Originally posted by [aborger](https://answers.ros.org/users/77931/aborger/) with karma: 106 on 2021-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ros_lucas](https://answers.ros.org/users/96102/ros_lucas/) on 2022-02-05**:
Thank you!! This is the solution for me and my ROS version is noetic.

**Comment by [wudi24k](https://answers.ros.org/users/113536/wudi24k/) on 2022-08-10**:
Could you please show how to fix it in the GUI? I am a beginner. I can not find switching operator.

**Comment by [ilan](https://answers.ros.org/users/142054/ilan/) on 2023-03-16**:
it worked for me as well. In simple words when the rqt_console pops up there is small setting icon on the top right corner. I changed the /rosout_agg to /rosout first and then run the turtle_sim_node and it worked out.